# Laplace Transform of a complex valued function with power argument

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm getting confused with the Laplace transform of a complex valued function.

For example, I know that:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-st} dt = \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}.
\end{equation}

However what if I have: 
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty (t+i)^n e^{-st} dt &= \int_0^\infty (t+i)^n e^{-s(t+i)}e^{i s} dt \\ 
&=e^{i s} \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}},
\end{align}
is this correct?

Thankks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

Note that for $i>0$,
$$\int_0^\infty (t+i)^n e^{-st} dt =\int_0^\infty (t+i)^n e^{-s(t+i)}e^{i s} dt=e^{i s}\int_{i}^\infty \tau^n e^{-s\tau}d\tau\not=e^{i s}\int_{0}^\infty \tau^n e^{-s\tau}d\tau,$$
so your last equality does not hold.

Try also for example the case where $n=1$ and $i=1$. Then 
$$\int_0^\infty (t+1) e^{-st} dt =\int_0^\infty te^{-st} dt+\int_0^\infty e^{-st} dt=\frac{1}{s^{2}}+\frac{1}{s}\not=\frac{e^{s}}{s^{2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

We can use the binomial theorem to write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty (t+i)^n e^{-st}\,dt&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(i)^{n-k}\int_0^\infty t^ke^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(i)^{n-k}\frac{k!}{s^{k+1}}
\end{align}$$