# Laplace transform of $(x+a)^n$

Tags: laplace-transform

Good day. Is there a laplace transform for this function? I know that if $a$ is a real number the Laplace transform is trivial and is just somewhat a Gamma function. But what if $a$ is an imaginary number, say $a=ib$, what is the Laplace transform? Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006572/laplace-transform-of-a-complex-valued-function-with-power-argument this may help

Comment: Just realised that you asked the original question.  I'm confused.

Comment: Lol i forgot that i already posted the same question. I should just delete this instead

Comment: No harm done$\\\\\$